# Is every solution of this matrix equation diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, block-matrices

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix with positive determinant. Suppose that $A$ is **diagonal**, and that

$ A=S-\lambda (S^T)^{-1}$, where $S$ is another invertible real $n \times n$ matrix, and $\lambda$ is some real number.

Must $S$ be diagonal?

**Edit:**

It suffices to prove that $S$ is symmetric, at least in the generic case where $A$ has distinct diagonal entries.

Indeed, the assumption is equivalent to $S^T(S-A)=\lambda I$, hence
$$S^T(S-A)=\lambda I=(\lambda I)^T=(S^T(S-A))^T=(S^T-A^T)S,$$ i.e.
$ S^TA=A^TS$. Since $A$ is symmetric, we obtain $ S^TA=AS$. Thus, if we assume $S^T=S$, then $S$ commutes with $A$, hence it must be diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's exceptions, at least in 2 dimensions: if
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} , $$
the equation is equivalent to
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a - \lambda d/\Delta & b + \lambda c/\Delta \\ c + \lambda b/\Delta & d - \lambda a/\Delta \end{pmatrix} , $$
where $\Delta = ad-bc$. Asking for the off-diagonal entries to be $0$ forces $ c = \pm b $ and $b = \sqrt{ \lambda \pm ad} $, provided that they are not $0$ to start with, and then $\Delta = \pm \lambda $, so either
$$ A = (a+d)I \quad \text{or} \quad A = \operatorname{diag}(a-d,-a+d) , $$
and the second is excluded since $\det{A}>0$. This will also extend to $n$ dimensions any time $A$ has two equal eigenvalues, of course. In particular, the second one will be allowed for matrices such as $\operatorname{diag}(\mu,-\mu,-1)$, so for dimensions larger than $2$, both types of solution are possible.

This leaves the general case of nonequal roots. We can improve on sufficiency of $S$ being symmetric to $S$ being (real-)normal:

In general, we have
$$ S^T A = S^T S - \lambda I \quad \text{and} \quad AS^T = SS^T - \lambda I ,  $$
and taking the transpose of the first gives
$$ AS = A^T S = S^T S - \lambda I $$
so $S^T-S = A^{-1} [S^T,S] $: if $S$ is normal, it is symmetric.

$ (S^T)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} (A - S) $, so $ S^T = \lambda (A-S)^{-1} $, and I'm now also stuck.

Comment: Thank you. Can you say how you reached the second equation (after the "and") - $\quad AS^T = SS^T - \lambda I$?

Comment: Multiply by $S^T$ on the right rather than the left.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We consider two possibilities:

1. All diagonal entries of $A=\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ have different moduli. The equation
   $$
   A=S-\lambda(S^T)^{-1},\tag{1}
   $$
   implies that both $AS^T=SS^T-\lambda I$ and $S^TA=S^TS-\lambda I$. Therefore both $AS^T$ and $S^TA$ are symmetric and
   \begin{cases}
   a_is_{ji}=(AS^T)_{ij}=(SA)_{ij}=s_{ij}a_j,\\
   s_{ji}a_j=(S^TA)_{ij}=(AS)_{ij}=a_is_{ij}.
   \end{cases}
   Since $|a_i|\ne|a_j|$, these two equalities imply that $s_{ij}=s_{ji}=0$. Hence $S$ is diagonal.
2. $A$ has two elements of the same moduli. When $A$ is $2\times2$, by comparing elements on both sides of $(1)$ directly, it can be shown that one of the following two cases must be true:

   - $S=\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&d},\ \lambda=-\det(S)$ and $A=(a+d)I$, or
   - $S=\pmatrix{a&-b\\ b&d},\ \lambda=\det(S)$ and $A=\pmatrix{a-d&0\\ 0&d-a}$.

   It follows that in the original problem, $S$ is not always diagonal. E.g.
   \begin{aligned}
   \pmatrix{6&0\\ 0&6} &= \pmatrix{7&2\\ 2&-1} - 11\pmatrix{7&2\\ 2&-1}^{-T},\\
   \pmatrix{8&0&0\\ 0&-8&0\\ 0&0&-4} &= \pmatrix{7&-2&0\\ 2&-1&0\\ 0&0&-1} + 3\,\pmatrix{7&-2&0\\ 2&-1&0\\ 0&0&-1}^{-T}.
   \end{aligned}